# Every time I divide I get 0.0

Tags: java, android

I am trying to make an app that splits the bill between people but whenever i try to divide the two numbers in the code it always gives me 0.0 . Why is this?

Here is the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public int x = 0;
    public double y = 1.00;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Button
        Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

        //EditText
        EditText nop = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        EditText cob = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);


        try{
            x = Integer.valueOf(nop.getText().toString());
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            x = 0;
        }

        try{
            y = Double.valueOf(cob.getText().toString());
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            y = 1.00;
        }


        //TextView
        final TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                 Double z = (y / x);
                tv.setText("You will each pay:" + (z));
            }
        });

    }
    }
```

Comment: Maybe your `Integer.valueOf`-Method throws an exception. Then you always have 0.0

Comment: @mrT You don't get 0.0 when you divide by zero. You get `NaN` or `Infinity`.

Comment: Assigning `x = 0` in the catch statement is a bit dangerous as this could lead to division by zero, which will return a division by zero exception.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Your right!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the values from `EditText` on click of the button otherwise you won't get the entered value because the code that are fetching the values of `x` and `y` gets executes as soon as you launch the app and no further fetching is done.

Do this

```
    final TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try{
                x = Integer.valueOf(nop.getText().toString());
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                x = 0;
            }

            try{
                y = Double.valueOf(cob.getText().toString());
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                y = 1.00;
            }

             Double z = (y / x);
            tv.setText("You will each pay:" + (z));
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 4):

My guess is that you don't evaluate the values after the click. The code of your try/catch should be in the onclick method.

Answer (score 0):

If there is an exception in the below code then x will be zero.

```
try {
    x = Integer.valueOf(nop.getText().toString());
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    x = 0;
}
```

Now because of the exception, you divide by zero & will get Infinity not 0.0

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure that the default number of participant is 1 not zero. If you set it to zero, you better not do the division and force the user to input good number or you must catch the exception for the division by zero.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public int x = 1;
    public double y = 1.00;
    public EditText nop;
    public EditText cob;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Button
        Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

        //EditText
        nop = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        cob = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);

        //TextView
        final TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try{
                    x = Integer.valueOf(nop.getText().toString());
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    x = 1;
                }

                try{
                    y = Double.valueOf(cob.getText().toString());
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    y = 1.00;
                }

                Double z = (y / x);
                tv.setText("You will each pay:" + (z));
            }
        });

    }
}
```